# Select the lowest date from a range and exclude another range

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I have a table (lets call it `audit`) that looks like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | recordId | status | mdate                   | type  | relatedId     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 3006     | A      | 2013-04-03 23:59:01.275 | type1 | 1             |
| 2  | 3025     | B      | 2013-04-04 00:00:02.134 | type1 | 1             |
| 3  | 4578     | A      | 2013-04-04 00:04:30.033 | type2 | 1             |
| 4  | 7940     | C      | 2013-04-04 00:04:32.683 | type1 | <NULL>        |
| 5  | 3006     | D      | 2013-04-04 00:04:32.683 | type1 | <NULL>        |
| 6  | 4822     | E      | 2013-04-04 00:04:32.683 | type2 | <NULL>        |
| 7  | 3006     | A      | 2013-04-04 00:06:54.033 | type1 | 2             |
| 8  | 3025     | C      | 2013-04-04 00:06:54.033 | type1 | 2             |
```

...and on for millions of rows.  And another table we'll call `related`:

```
+-------------+
| id | source |
+-------------+
| 1  | src_X  |
| 2  | src_Y  |
| 3  | src_Z  |
| 4  | src_X  |
| 5  | src_X  |
```

...and on for hundreds of thousands of rows.

There are more columns than these on both tables but this is all we need to describe the problem.  The column `relatedId` joins to the `related` table.  `recordId` also joins to another table, and there will be multiple entries in `audit` with the same `recordId`.

I'm trying to create a query that will produce the following output:

```
+-----------------+
| source  | count |
+-----------------+
| src_X   | 1643  |
| src_Y   | 255   |
| NULL    | 729   |
+-----------------+
```

The count is the number of records within `audit` that have a given `type` (eg. `"type1"`) and are within a set of statuses (eg. `"A", "B", "C"`) which are then left outer joined to `related` and grouped by `source`.

The catch is that I only want to include records from within `audit` that are within a certain date range, and I also only want to join from `audit` to `related` on the oldest entry within that range for each `recordId`.  Further, I want to ignore any records that match the `type` and `status` criteria, but have an entry for the same `recordId` that is older than the range of dates.

So, to clarify from the above example data:  Lets say I want a type of `type1` and the status values of `"A", "B", "C"` with a date range of `2013-04-04` to `2013-04-05`.  Rows 2 and 4 would be included in the count.  Row 3 is excluded as it has the incorrect `type`.  Row 5 is excluded as the status is incorrect.  Row 6 is excluded because the  both the status and the type are incorrect.  Row 1 is excluded as it is outside the date range.  Row 7 is also excluded, as there is another row (row 1) that matches the status and type criteria with the same `recordId` that is older than the start of the date range.  Row 8 is excluded as both row 8 and row 2 have the same `recordId` and match the criteria, but we only count the oldest record of the two within the range.

In other words, I want to count only the first time an entry for a given recordId appears in the table and is within the target date range.

We've come up with the following:

```
WITH data (recordId, id) AS (
    SELECT a.recordId, MIN(a.id)
    FROM audit a
    WHERE a.status in ('A','B','C')
        AND type = 'type1'
    GROUP BY a.recordId
)
SELECT r.source, COUNT(*)
FROM data d
    JOIN audit a ON d.id = a.id
    LEFT JOIN related r ON a.relatedId = r.id
WHERE a.mdate >= '2013-04-04 00:00:00.000'
    and a.mdate < '2013-04-05 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY r.source
```

This will be run on MSSQL Server 2008, and currently relies on the fact that the audit table id's are autogenerated.  Since the id's are generated at the point the record is inserted, and the mdate is also the insert timestamp and the records are never updated once inserted, I think this is OK.  The query appears to give the correct output on a limited set of test data, but I was hoping for a second opinion.

- Does this query look ok?
- Can its performance be improved?

Comment: A date range in your computed table expression would probably improve performance.

Comment: Good point.  Adding `AND a.mdate < '2013-04-05 00:00:00.000'` to the computed table will help limit the number of records it returns.

Comment: To improve the Query Performance take care of the indexing too. Use indexing on WHERE Clause Fields, Join Fields, and test the Performance again..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to rank the records based on RecordId and mDate, then limit the results to where the first occurance is between your specified dates.

```
WITH data  AS 
(   SELECT  a.relatedId, a.mdate, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.RecordId ORDER BY a.mdate)
    FROM    audit a
    WHERE   a.status in ('A','B','C')
    AND     type = 'type1'
)
SELECT  r.source, [Count] = COUNT(*)
FROM    data d
        LEFT JOIN related r 
            ON d.relatedId = r.id
WHERE   d.rn = 1
AND     d.mdate >= '2013-04-04 00:00:00.000'
AND     d.mdate < '2013-04-05 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY r.source;
```

I am not sure this will perform any better than your current solution, but will solve the problem of relying on chronological inserts. If chronological inserts are not a problem you could change the `ORDER BY` within the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to use ID, as sorting on the clustered key will be faster.

Performance tuning is very difficult to do from the outside looking in, in order to even guess at it we would need to see the indexes on the relevant tables, and the execution plan for the query. Then you can identify the bottle necks, and what indexes might improve performance.

[This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a13cd/2) shows the two queries (mine and yours) end up with the same result, however when you look at the IO statistics you can see for your query you get:

```
(2 row(s) affected)
Table 'Related'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Audit'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Using ROW_NUMBER() you get:

```
(2 row(s) affected)
Table 'Related'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Audit'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

The key factor being one less logical read. A quick look at the execution plan shows that the ROW_NUMBER() solution has one less branch and is estimated at 37% of the batch cost, whereas your solution is 63%, so on this small set of data it would appear to be a performance improvement.

[image]

**However** there is only so much I can tell from such a small sample of data, some solutions do not scale well, and as I have said it will depend on your data size and distrubution. My suggestion would be try different solutions, find the bottle necks by examining the IO statistics and the execution plan.

For example, looking at the execution plan for the CTE this accounts for 50% of the query cost for my query:

[image]

By adding this index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Audit_ALL ON Audit (recordId, MDate, RelatedID, status, type)
```

I was able to reduce this to 18% of the query cost.

[image]

However, in practicality without knowing more I can't say for definite this index would (a) help this query with your data and (b) that it wouldn't cause other problems with your database by slowing insert/updates down.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!